# Cocos2d-x replace Texture repeatedly

Tags: textures, cocos2d-x

in Cocos2d-x, 
I want to swap sprite's texture repeatedly.

my swap function is below...

```
void GameScene::swapSpriteTexture(CCSprite *a, CCTexture2D *b)
{
    CCTexture2D *tmp = a->getTexture();
    a->setTexture(b);
    b = tmp;
}
```

and I call the function liks this,

```
this->swapSpriteTexture(aSprite, m_TextureSlot);
```

when I call swap function, first time, it works well. 
the sprite's texture changes well.
but when I call the function again, it doesn't change.

m_TextureSlot is

```
m_TextureSlot=(CCTexture2D *)CCTextureCache::sharedTextureCache()->addImage("smile.png");
```

is this cache problem?
any idea plz...

Answer (score 1):

my mistakes...

I changes the function like this,

```
void GameScene::swapSpriteTexture(CCSprite *a, CCTexture2D **b)
{
    CCTexture2D *tmp = a->getTexture();
    a->setTexture(*b);
    *b = tmp;
}
```

and I call the swap function.

```
this->swapSpriteTexture(aSprite, &m_TextureSlot);
```

then, it works fantastically. : )

Comment: because... we have to change m_TextureSlot's value, not b's value. So it should be called by reference of m_TextureSlot's address.